# how to route mutliple urls to one action in .net core mvc while retriving the url paramenters in variables

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, routes

I want more than one URL to land to one action (function). But inside the function, I want to see which URL hit the action. If I use variables like `[Route("{FirstParam?}/{SecondParam?}")]` then all of my routes come to this particular action which I don't want of course.

For Example

```
[RequestFilter]
[Route("{FirstParam?}/{SecondParam?}")]
public IActionResult handleURL(string FirstParam, string SecondParam)
{
 return showCategory(FirstParam, SecondParam);
}
```

if I use this above method then I do get URL in my variables but this way all of the URLs land to this action even the images URL like `<img src="/images/products/car-maclaren">`

So the other option I thought is the following but I am unable to retrieve URLs in variable to process corresponding function accordingly

```
[RequestFilter]
[Route("cars/{minor?}")]
[Route("ships/{minor?}")]

public IActionResult Category(string minor)
{
   string major = ?? // how to retrieve whether cars URL hit this action or ships URL
   
   //some common work for both categories
   
   if(major == "cars")
   {
   // do some specific work for cars
    return View("carsDisplay","carsViewModel");
   }
   else if(major == "ships")
   {
   // do some specific work for ships
   return View("shipsDisplay","shipsViewModel");
   }
    return View("Error");
 }
```

the last option is to declare each route separately and address them in separate action funciton, but that needs much repetitive code since i have many categories.

Answer (score 1):

Controller actions map easily to different views. If your controller actions end up at different views, then you would be best off simply defining seperate controller routes for your categories. If you have common logic you can also define private functions in your controller or in another part of your application to prevent code duplication. Relying on parsing your route in the controller actions seems brittle.